# how to design great design's for a Android Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

**What I'm Trying to do**

At the moment I'm creating a design for my Activity, which has different kind of "boxes" in it. Every of those "boxes", has diffrent informations in it. I created the design by hand on a piece of paper, but I won't get the idea down in my .xml!!

**Question**

On the bottom of this post you'll find a copyed "box" which I'd like to create for my app. Please help me to realize this, because I really don't get how to do this in my XML! I'm working with Android 4.0 (ICS).

[image: Design of the box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/box_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Box Title" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/box_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/box_content_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hans Max" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/box_content_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Maxiburger 12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/box_content_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8002, Muster" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/box_button"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tried it out! Thank you for your super fast anwser! That helped really much!!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: I prefer it if we do *not* the work for them. This is a basic layout and they should learn it sooner or later so why not now?

Comment: @WarrenFaith after i saw this layout, I learned many things. First of all I prefer to do the work by my own, because I want to learn this! No offence! I'm really gratefull! And +1 for your comment, because you're right! I see it the same way but sometimes it helps to learn it, somehow you need to see how it is structured, and built!

Answer (score 2):

I give you the pseudo layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        full width
        id:infobox/>
    <Button
        layoutParentRight
        below infobox/>
    <TextView
        layout_below infobox
        toLeftOf button/>
    // repeat the textView above and always below the previous one
</RelativeLayout>
```

With LinearLayouts:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView infobox/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <TextView />
            <TextView />
            <TextView />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you see it is much more complex and bloated. As I always get confused by horizontal/vertical orientation I leave this to you to find out :)
Just experiment and if you can't get it to work, update your answer with the layout you tried.

Comment: allright, but as I know are there many problems when the screen resolution changes or not? Is this possible to realize with Linearlayouts?

Comment: Sure, you than need three of them. The "problem" with the screen resolution remains. You just need to make it as dynamic as possible.

Comment: if you use relative layout without any hardcoding it will suit for all resolution.

Comment: allright, i tryied to do this with 3 LinearLayouts.. but it didn't work at all :( how should that look like? Thx for your help!!

Comment: `RelativeLayout`s are usually better than `LinearLayout`s when it comes to supporting multiple screen sizes and orientations. Check these out:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: updated my answer, not sure why @trumpetlicks deleted his answer as it was a good one...

Comment: +1 Funny that nobody even mentioned the biggest problem of `LinearLayout`s...apart from code clarity and readability, the combination of nested `LinearLayout`s with `View`s that use a `layout_weight` can incur in a dramatic performance penalty because the child `View`s will need to be measured twice. In this example, it shouldn't be a big issue but it's a good practice to avoid...especially when repeating data-bound items inside a list